# Using EJBs in a JAX-RS (CXF) service and TomEE 7.0.1

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, openejb, tomee-7

I'm trying to do the following (lots of details, sorry...):

Have a jax-rs service with an `@EJB` to avoid jndi lookup. Something like

```
@Path("rest/my-path)
public class Service {

  @EJB
  private MyEJB me;

  @Path("foo")
  @GET
  public String foo() {
    return me.foo();
  }
}
```

Using `CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet` and limit the `url-pattern`. web.xml should be something like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.example.Service
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So theoretically `http://localhost:8080/my-app/rest/my-path/foo` will call, you guessed right, `foo()`

TomEE's log supports this:

> Setting the server's publish address to be /  REST Application:
>
> http://localhost:8080/my-app/
>
> URI: http://localhost:8080/my-app/rest/my-path
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/my-app/rest/my-path/foo

But actually, the combination of the servlet-mapping and the jaxrs resolver makes

http://localhost:8080/my-app/rest/my-path/foo return **404**

and (pay attention to the double /rest/rest/)

http://localhost:8080/my-app/rest/rest/my-path/foo actually invoke the method but **MyEJB** is null

Didn't find any combination of servlet-mapping and service path and `jaxrs.address` that makes the root url return the index.html and the correct service url is calling foo and MyEJB is not null

Any ideas om how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this from your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.example.Service
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

TomEE scans your application automatically and adds any REST controllers.  During startup, the logs will contain the path to your REST url. You may need to add an `Application.class` like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest-prefix")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(Service.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!
I'm using the Application solution. What bugs me is the lack of documentation and the (too) loose coupling between the servlet and jax-rs specifications.
Was wondering if someone out there can explain this...

Comment: Random odd fact: Under the covers, JAX-RS is a servlet, it just comes built into the server :)

Comment: And speaking of documentation, Use Oracle's official guide to Java EE or use TomEE's examples page! They always show you the "correct" way to do things. Your Example would be what you would need to do for Vanilla Tomcat